# SVNKit Library Dynamic User Credentials

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, svnkit

Is there any way to check-in file/folder using SVNKit library as multiple users for checking into SVN repository without creating multiple SVNCommitClient objects. So that the entire transaction will be single.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

Subversion commits are atomic.  That means all of the commits are made, or none of them are made.  This atomicity applies to a single user.

If you have multiple users, you have multiple atomic commits.

You can either have your multiple user group use the same log in and password, so you can make all of the individual commits atomic, or you can break up your Subversion commit so that each person in your user group makes a separate atomic commit.